# How to filter databases in list based on column with different name

Tags: r, list, dplyr, purrr

I have a list that includes different databases with different informations.
The first column of every database includes the informations that I need to create graphs. I need to filter information based on external vector referred to first column.

For example:

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("cars_model") %>% as.data.frame()
mtcars3 <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("cars_model_second") %>% as.data.frame()
list_two_database <- list(mtcars2, mtcars3)

model_to_select <- c("Fiat 128", "Honda Civic", "Lotus Europa")
```

Is there a way to filter the list based on THE FIRST COLUMN OF EACH DATABASE included in the list (cars_model and cars_model_second) WITHOUT RENAME THE COLUMN ITSELF?

The goal is to obtain a list that includes the two databases each with the three model.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works by extracting the first column name as a string `first_col` and then converting this string into a form that can be used within dplyr:

```r
mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("cars_model") %>% as.data.frame()
mtcars3 <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("cars_model_second") %>% as.data.frame()
list_two_database <- list(mtcars2, mtcars3)

model_to_select <- c("Fiat 128", "Honda Civic", "Lotus Europa")

func = function(df){
  first_col = colnames(df)[1]
  
  filter(df, !!sym(first_col) %in% model_to_select)
}

lapply(list_two_database, func)
```

Notes:

- `sym(.)` is used to turn a text string into a symbol
- `!!` only works inside dplyr commands and turns symbols into variables

Used together you have something like:

```r
var = "my_col"
df %>% filter(!!sym(var) == 1)
```

Which is equivalent to `df %>% filter(my_col == 1)`

Comment: Thank you so much Simon.S.A. Although I preferred a solution without a function I like it.
I never use !!sym(x) ... what does it mean in a very simply way?
Maybe it allow to "filter" to act even if there are different string as first column?

Comment: `!!sym` lets us use the text inside a variable as the column name. I have added 3further explanation to my answer.